# How to pass variable from test function to fixture in pytest?

Tags: pytest

Below is the example code from contest.py

```
@pytest.fixture
def required_input(var1): # not sure if i can pass var1 to the fixture.
    return var1+"_test"
```

below is the test case from test_code.py

```
def test_case1(required_input):
    x = required_input("tt")  # Not sure if it can be called like this.
    assert 'tt_test' == x
```

How can I pass variable from my test function to a fixture?

Answer (score 0):

A fixture can be a function:

```
@pytest.fixture
def required_input(): # not sure if i can pass var1 to the fixture.
    return lambda var1: return var1+"_test"
```

Comment: How can I pass var1 variable to fixture from my test?